# Data Binding in GridView

Tags: c#, data-binding, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to bind some data to a `GridView` in Windows 8.1's `Hub` control.

Currently, I have a `DataTemplate` set up under `Page.Resources` as follows:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="Standard240x320ItemTemplateFAV">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="320" Height="240">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding FavImage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FavTitle}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Height="48" Margin="15,0,15,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I then have this `HubSection`:

```
            <HubSection x:Name="FavHub" Padding="40,60,40,0" >
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="itemGridView"
                    Margin="-4,-4,0,0"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard240x320ItemTemplateFAV}"
                    SelectionMode="Single"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                    ItemClick="ItemView_ItemClick">
                </GridView>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HubSection>
```

I use this code to add the DataContext:

```
FavHub.DataContext = new FavData(Constants.getImage("1002"), "No Favourites");
```

Where the FavData class is:

```
    public class FavData
    {
        public static string FavImage { get; set; }
        public static string FavTitle { get; set; }

        public FavData() { }

        public FavData(string itemImageSet, string itemNameSet)
        {
            FavImage = itemImageSet;
            FavTitle = itemNameSet;
        }
    }
```

However, no data shows up in the HubSection. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the list of `Items`: `ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"`

Comment: Oh phooey, that was it. Don't know why I didn't notice that earlier. Probably a horrid question now but, any idea what it should be? Thanks! >.<

Comment: A `List<FavData>` would work as an example. `ObservableCollection<FavData>` another.

Comment: Sorry but I'm really new to data binding, not sure how to put the above into the XAML. What exactly do I change the ItemSource property to?

Comment: Oh, I was suggesting you set the `DataContext` property to a list of `FavData`, and change the binding to `{Binding}` which means bind to "self", rather than a property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to bind a list, like a `List<FavData>` or an `ObservableCollection<FavData>` to the Hub.

Right now, you've got a `GridView` that among many other attributes, includes initialization of the `ItemsSource` property. This property is used as the source for a list of items.

```
<GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
</GridView>
```

The binding is specified as `{Binding Items}` which means that for whatever object is bound currently to the Hub, grab the List stored on the `Items` property. As you currently had set a single `FavData` instance to the Hub via the `DataContext` property, and it did not have a property called `Items`, there was nothing to display.

So, my suggestion is to create a list of `FavData` instances and bind that to the Hub instance instead. If you want to directly bind the list rather than store the list in another "parent" object, you'll also need to adjust the `Binding` to refer to "self" rather than a specific property. For that, you just use the syntax: `{Binding}`. It just means, "bind to me." So, the GridView will look for the list of items directly on the bound object (the list of `FavData`).

```
<GridView x:Name="itemGridView"
    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
</GridView>
```

And in the C#:

```
List<FavData> favs = new List<FavData>();
favs.Add(new FavData(Constants.getImage("1002"), "No Favourites"));
FavHub.DataContext = favs;
```